# Do I need to restart td-agent forwarders if the host server behind my dns changes?

Tags: elasticsearch, dns, kibana, fluentd

Using td-agent to forward my logs to a log aggregate node running kibana/elasticsearch/td-agent, I have my forwarders config set up like:

```
  <match mytag.**>
    type forward
    flush_interval 10s
    <server>
      host myserver.com
      port 24224
    </server>
  </match>
```

My log aggregate node is mapped via DNS  to **myserver.com**

I configured everything and logs are collecting on my aggregate node just fine. Then I decide to spin up a new aggregate node to test a different configuration. I change my dns to send **myserver.com** to this new node instead.

I am able to access the new Kibana instance on the new node via dns just fine, but my forwarders all seem to be having an issue connecting. td-agent logs on forwarders show:

```
2015-12-24 16:11:26 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2015-12-24 16:20:30 +0000 error_class="RuntimeError" error="no nodes are available" plugin_id="object:3fd1a993acf0"
```

The "no nodes are available" portion tells me that it can't connect to the forward server. I gave it some time but had the same result each time td-agent retried. I did a restart of td-agent and everything connected just fine.

Do I really need to restart td-agent on every server that is forwarding in order to connect to the new aggregate node? I was really hoping that td-agent could just use the DNS to dynamically shift.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe I need a load balancer to handle the swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expire_dns_cache` parameter may help.

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_forward#expirednscache